# Transaction Reverted even though I have a payable fallback function to receive eth, when I deploy without sending eth it works

Tags: solidity

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

import "./Allowance.sol";

contract SharedWallet is Allowance {

    event MoneySent(address indexed _beneficiary, uint _amount);
    event MoneyReceived(address indexed _from, uint _amount);

    function withdrawMoney(address payable _to, uint _amount) public ownerOrAllowed(_amount) {
        require(_amount <= address(this).balance, "Contract doesn't own enough money");
        if(!isOwner()) {
            reduceAllowance(msg.sender, _amount);
        }
        emit MoneySent(_to, _amount);
        _to.transfer(_amount);

    }

    function renounceOwnership() public override onlyOwner {
        revert("can't renounceOwnership here"); //not possible with this smart contract
    }

    fallback () external payable {
        emit MoneyReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send Ether to the contract as you deploy it? As I do not think you can do that easily. Well, there is a hacky way. Ethereum contract address is deterministic, i.e. knowing the creator's address and their nonce you can calculate the future address of your smart contract. And then send ETH to that address prior to deploying the contract.